# How to add white space between matplotlib axes in a single figure

Tags: matplotlib

I have 5 axes on a single matplotlib figure. Is there a way that I can add white space between only 2 axes?

I would like something similar to `fig.subplots_adjust()` but for axes objects so that the adjustment only affects the positioning of 1 ax and not all axes[image: example].

Comment: You may want to have a look at this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137991/matplotlib-get-and-set-axes-position).

Comment: You have 3 options: (1) position the axes to you liking via `ax = fig.add_axes([x0,y0,width,height])` or if they already exist, `ax.set_position([x0,y0,width,height])`. (2) Add an extra row of axes, which is as high as the extra space needed (3) Use two different gridspecs, one offset by extra_space from the other.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Excellent! Thanks for the comprehensive comment, I went for option 2. If you submit your commit as an answer I'll accept.