# matplotlib change size of subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes, subplot

I try to make a figure with different subplots. In the example the left panel is an `imshow` image and it is a bit too small. How could I enlarge `ax1`? In order to have the colorbar at the level of the x-axes of `ax2` and `ax3`?

The code and output is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,5.5))
ax1=plt.subplot2grid((1,3),(0,0))
ax2=plt.subplot2grid((1,3),(0,1))
ax3=plt.subplot2grid((1,3),(0,2))


image=np.random.random_integers(1,10,size=(100,100))
cax=ax1.imshow(image,interpolation="none",aspect='equal')
cbar=fig.colorbar(cax,ax=ax1,orientation=u'horizontal')

x=np.linspace(0,1)
ax2.plot(x,x**2)
ax3.plot(x,x**3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a cue from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195758/set-matplotlib-colorbar-size-to-match-graph), you can adjust the layout of your `colorbar` with [AxisDivider](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#axesdivider).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,5.5))
ax1=plt.subplot2grid((1,3),(0,0))
ax2=plt.subplot2grid((1,3),(0,1))
ax3=plt.subplot2grid((1,3),(0,2))

image=np.random.random_integers(1,10,size=(100,100))
im = ax1.imshow(image,interpolation="none",aspect='equal')

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
cax = divider.append_axes("bottom",size="5%",pad=0.7)
cbar=fig.colorbar(im,cax=cax,orientation=u'horizontal')

x=np.linspace(0,1)
ax2.plot(x,x**2)
ax3.plot(x,x**3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

`pad=0.7` looked about right to me. You may need to play around with that parameter as well as `figsize` height to get it exactly the way you want.