# How to change color bar to align with main plot in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, plot

When plotting matrix with imshow in Matplotlib, how to change `colorbar` legend bar size, location, font and other parameters?

Here I created an example code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def plot_matrix(mat, title='example', cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    plt.imshow(mat, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()

data = np.random.random((20, 20))

plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=12)

plot_matrix(data)
```

[image]

In a real use case, I got complex labels and the legend bar becomes much higher then the matrix itself. I want to change the legend bar to make the plot more efficiently use the space.

I found a [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar) for the `matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar`, however have not figure out a good way to set the size, location and font size for the color legend bar.

Comment: you have many possibilities using `make_axes_locatable`, [as detailed here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18195921/832621)

Comment: +1, `make_axes_locatable` method calculates the location and size of axes at drawing time.  Alternatively, we can specify the location and size of axes before drawing time.  See below:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imshow` enforces a 1:1 aspect (by default, but you can change it with `aspect` parameter), which makes things a little trickier.  To always get consistent result, I might suggest manually specify the size of axes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def plot_matrix(mat, figsize, title='example', cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    ax = plt.axes([0, 0.05, 0.9, 0.9 ]) #left, bottom, width, height
    #note that we are forcing width:height=1:1 here, 
    #as 0.9*8 : 0.9*8 = 1:1, the figure size is (8,8)
    #if the figure size changes, the width:height ratio here also need to be changed
    im = ax.imshow(mat, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    ax.grid(False)
    ax.set_title(title)
    cax = plt.axes([0.95, 0.05, 0.05,0.9 ])
    plt.colorbar(mappable=im, cax=cax)
    return ax, cax

data = np.random.random((20, 20))
ax, cax = plot_matrix(data, (8,8))
```

Now you have the axis where the colorbar is plotted in, `cax`. You can do a lot of thing with that, say, rotate the labels, using `plt.setp(cax.get_yticklabels(), rotation=45)`

[image]

Comment: Thanks CT! I followed your way to implement my methods and it works perfectly. The bar size is aligned well. I am also be able to set the font size of x and y ticks while creating them. Another thing I also want to set the font of colorbar label. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are welcome!  Change font would be: `plt.setp(cax.get_yticklabels(), fontname='Times New Roman')
` assuming you have `Time New Roman` installed on your box.