# add a colorbar to a calmap plot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

this is my first post here!

I'm using calmap to plot nice calendar plot to analyze some data. The calendar plot is using a colormap to show contrast between days. The problem I have is that calmap does not provide friendly tool to display a colorbar associated with the calendar plot. I would like to know if one of you have a solution to this. The ideal would be that the colorbar is set for the entire figure and not only one axis.

the documentation of calmap :http://pythonhosted.org/calmap/

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import calmap # pip install calmap

%matplotlib inline

df=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(500,1)
                ,index=pd.date_range(start='2014-01-01 00:00:00',freq='1D',periods =500)
                ,columns=['data'])

fig,ax=calmap.calendarplot(df['data'],
                    fillcolor='grey', linewidth=0,cmap='RdYlGn',
                    fig_kws=dict(figsize=(17,8)))

fig.suptitle('Calendar view' ,fontsize=20,y=1.08)
```

the calmap plot example

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Digging into calmap code here [martijnvermaat/calmap](https://github.com/martijnvermaat/calmap/blob/master/calmap/__init__.py) I understand that

- calendarplot calls several yearplot for each subplot (twice in your case)
- yearplot create a first `ax.pcolormesh` with background and then another one with the actual data, plus a bunch of other thing.

To dig into the object related to an axis you can use (I assume your code import and data initialization before anything here) :

```
ax[0].get_children()

[<matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh at 0x11ebd9e10>,
 <matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh at 0x11ebe9210>, <- that's the one we need!
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x11e85a910>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x11e865250>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x11e85ad10>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x11e865490>,
 <matplotlib.axis.XAxis at 0x11e85a810>,
 <matplotlib.axis.YAxis at 0x11e74ba90>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x11e951dd0>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x11e951e50>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x11e951ed0>,
 <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x11e951f10>]
```

now, we can use `fig.colorbar` (`plt.colorbar` is a wrapper around this function) as suggested in this answer
[Matplotlib 2 Subplots, 1 Colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23795901/1435167) :

```
fig,ax=calmap.calendarplot(df['data'],
                    fillcolor='grey', linewidth=0,cmap='RdYlGn',
                    fig_kws=dict(figsize=(17,8)))

fig.colorbar(ax[0].get_children()[1], ax=ax.ravel().tolist())
```

this produces a vertical colobar referencing color the only in the first plot, but the color are the same for all the plots.

[image]

I'm still playing with position better the axis and an horizontal one, but it should be easy from here.

As bonus, for a single yearplot:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cax = calmap.yearplot(df, year=2014, ax=ax, cmap='YlGn')
fig.colorbar(cax.get_children()[1], ax=cax, orientation='horizontal')
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks for the easy and clean solution

Answer (score 3):

Putting together @kidpixo answer and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18195921/153330) from @bogatron, I prepared a self contained example that 'does the obvious thing', creating a colorbar on the right side of the calmap and matching its height.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import calmap # pip install calmap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
%matplotlib inline

df=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(500,1)
                ,index=pd.date_range(start='2014-01-01 00:00:00',freq='1D',periods =500)
                ,columns=['data'])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cax = calmap.yearplot(df.data, year=2014, ax=ax, cmap='YlGn')
# fig.colorbar(cax.get_children()[1], ax=cax, orientation='horizontal')
divider = make_axes_locatable(cax)
lcax = divider.append_axes("right", size="2%", pad=0.5)
fig.colorbar(cax.get_children()[1], cax=lcax)
```

[image: example calmap with side colorbar]