# Undesired colorbar and axis labels/plot titles interaction

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

Dear fellow Python users,

I try to produce colormaps by combining LinearSegmentedColormap in combination with Imshow, using matplotlib library, and I'm having a hard time with the actual colorbar.

The colorbar does not behaves the way I want by default, that is, it is much too big for my graph. By default, I get this:

[image: default colorbar]

So, I used the following code lines to fix colorbar height, in reference to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195758/set-matplotlib-colorbar-size-to-match-graph/18195921#18195921):

```
ax = plt.gca()
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
plt.colorbar(img2, cax=cax)
```

An then I got this very strange result:

[image: fixed graph]

I'm not able to figure out why the added code lines interact with my axis and plot titles... Why do they go with the colorbar?

Here is the complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pylab  as pylab
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable       

#random data for example
clmap = np.random.rand(30,500)

#plot 2D color map
fig = plt.figure()
cmap2 = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap', ['blue','green','red'], 256)
img2 = plt.imshow(clmap,interpolation='nearest',cmap = cmap2,origin='lower')
ax = plt.gca()
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
fig.colorbar(img2, cmap = cmap2, cax=cax)
plt.title('color map of atom probab at iteration 1')
plt.xlabel('atom id')
plt.ylabel('layer')
fig.savefig("map_p_1.png")
plt.gcf().clear()
```

Comment: Without showing us the actualy code in form of a [mcve], we are also not "able to figure out why the added code lines interact with my axis and plot titles".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing the pyplot state machine (`plt`) with the object oriented API.
After creating the second axes object (`cax`), it will be the current axes. All pyplot commands comming afterwards are applied to this axes.

The easiest way out is to apply the pyplot commands before creating the new axes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable       

#random data for example
clmap = np.random.rand(30,500)

#plot 2D color map
fig = plt.figure()
plt.title('color map of atom probab at iteration 1')
plt.xlabel('atom id')
plt.ylabel('layer')
cmap2 = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap', ['blue','green','red'], 256)
img2 = plt.imshow(clmap,interpolation='nearest',cmap = cmap2,origin='lower')
ax = plt.gca()
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
fig.colorbar(img2, cmap = cmap2, cax=cax)

fig.savefig("map_p_1.png")

plt.show()
```