# How do I plot data with color from my model onto matplotlib Basemap? Why is data not showing up?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to get my data output from my model plotted on Basemap. I can see the map, but not the points. What is the issue? I am using the latest version of scikit-learn and basemap for python 2.7. I have the following code:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('powerplants.csv') # CSV file that contains latitude column, longitude column, and id for the powerplant
colormap = np.arange(500)
labels = modeloutput.labels_ # assume this is output of my model

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='w', frame_on=True)
fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)
map_points = [...] # assume this is a list populated with coordinates from the csv
# Plot the clusters on the map
# m is a basemap object
m.scatter(
         [geom.x for geom in map_points],
         [geom.y for geom in map_points],
         20, marker='o', lw=.25,
         c = colormap(labels.astype(float)),
         alpha =0.9, antialiased=True,
         zorder=3)
m.fillcontinents(color='#555555')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Don't really know what you data looks like. What does `colormap(labels.astype(float))` mean? A callable ndarray? Have you got any error message? Is that possible you can provide a more complete and verifiable example?

Comment: I am not sure, it is output of a kmeans model. The data is just a csv file with latitude longitudes. Without astype(float) it doesn't do anything either. No error messages displayed, but nothing plotting either except for the background basemap itself.

Comment: My suspect is the problem comes from `colormap(labels.astype(float))`, where `colormap` is a `ndarray` and might not be callable. I would say seeing your data or have a relevant sample is helpful in solving your problem. Just realize I've answered another question from you yesterday. Sorry that these couldn't solve your problem. I tried my best and made an example below which might be close to your example. Hopefully that helps a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example is modified from the [official example](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html). Key parts for using colormap in scatter plot are:

1. `x.data` and `y.data` are transformed coordinates.
2. `c = np.random.randint(1, 500, size=len(lats))` are values mapping to a color in the colormap corresponding to each point.

Some parts which might be not necessary for you are:

> ```
> import urllib, os
> from netCDF4 import Dataset
> import numpy as np
>
> filename, _ = urllib.urlretrieve('http://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/tabledap/apdrcArgoAll.nc?longitude,latitude,time&longitude>=0&longitude<=360&latitude>=-90&latitude<=90&time>=2010-01-01&time<=2010-01-08&distinct()')
> dset = Dataset(filename)
> lats = dset.variables['latitude'][:]
> lons = dset.variables['longitude'][:]
> dset.close()
> os.remove(filename)
> c = np.random.randint(1, 500, size=len(lats))
>
> x, y = m(lons,lats)
> ```
>
> This part is used for generating an data sample. You might want to replace it with your real data.
>
> ```
> from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
>
> divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
> fig.colorbar(pc, cax=divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05))
> ```
>
> This is a direct application of [bogatron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195758/set-matplotlib-colorbar-size-to-match-graph#18195921) to make the size of colorbar matches the plot. It's your choice of keeping it or not.

```
import urllib, os

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

# data downloaded from the form at
# http://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/tabledap/apdrcArgoAll.html
filename, _ = urllib.urlretrieve('http://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/tabledap/apdrcArgoAll.nc?longitude,latitude,time&longitude>=0&longitude<=360&latitude>=-90&latitude<=90&time>=2010-01-01&time<=2010-01-08&distinct()')
dset = Dataset(filename)
lats = dset.variables['latitude'][:]
lons = dset.variables['longitude'][:]
dset.close()
os.remove(filename)
c = np.random.randint(1, 500, size=len(lats))

# draw map with markers for float locations
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='w', frame_on=True)
fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)
m = Basemap(lon_0=180, ax=ax)
x, y = m(lons,lats)
pc = m.scatter(x.data, y.data, 20, marker='o', c=c, lw=.25, alpha =0.9, antialiased=True, zorder=3, cmap='summer')
m.fillcontinents(color='#555555')
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
fig.colorbar(pc, cax=divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05))
plt.show()
```

[image]