# How to add a colorbar to subplot2grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, colormap

This should be really simple but for some reason I can't get it to work:

```
def plot_image(images, heatmaps):
    plt.figure(0)
    for i, (image, map) in enumerate(zip(images, heatmaps)):
        a = plt.subplot2grid((2,4), (0,i))
        a.imshow(image)
        a = plt.subplot2grid((2,4), (1,i))
        a.imshow(map)
        plt.colorbar(a, fraction=0.046, pad=0.04) 
    plt.show()
```

The values in colorbar line are taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26720422), but I'm getting:

> AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'

I'm plotting 2 by 4 grid of images, and I'd like to display vertical colorbars to the right from each image, or perhaps only next to the rightmost images in the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plt.colorbar` expects an image as its first argument (or in general a ScalarMappable), not an axes.

```
plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax, ...)
```

Therefore your example should read:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_image(images, heatmaps):
    fig = plt.figure(0)
    for i, (image, map) in enumerate(zip(images, heatmaps)):
        ax = plt.subplot2grid((2,4), (0,i))
        im = ax.imshow(image)
        ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2,4), (1,i))
        im2 = ax2.imshow(map)
        fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, fraction=0.046, pad=0.04) 
        fig.colorbar(im2, ax=ax2, fraction=0.046, pad=0.04) 
    plt.show()

a = [np.random.rand(5,5) for i in range(4)]
b = [np.random.rand(5,5) for i in range(4)]
plot_image(a,b)
```

[image]