# How to make 3D scatter plot color bar adjust to the Z axis size?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have trying to visualize my data from pandas column as 3D scatter plot. I am facing the problem to adjust the color bar match to the exact size of my z axis.

My code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

s = pd.read_csv('FahrerVP8.out_1.csv', index_col=0)

ax = plt.figure()
three_d = ax.gca(projection='3d')
three_d1 = three_d.scatter(s['Latitude'], s['Longitude'],s['Mean_ VehicleSpeed'], c =s['Mean_ VehicleSpeed'] )
three_d.set_xlabel('Latitude')
three_d.set_ylabel('Longitude')
three_d.set_zlabel('Mean Vehicle Speed')


plt.colorbar(three_d1)
plt.show()
```

My Result

[image]

I want my color bar height to be adjusted with z axis height.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want. Do you want to change the colors? What do you mean by "color plot to be adjust with axes"?

Comment: 1. I want color bar height to be same as like z axis height.@AdamBellaïche

Comment: May be you find answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195758/set-matplotlib-colorbar-size-to-match-graph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to modify the size of your color bar is to use "shrink" axes property like this:

```
plt.colorbar(three_d1, shrink=0.5) # an example
```

But you need to find the good value by hands.It could be 0.5 like 0.7.

However, you can try to calcul the needed value of shrink by getting the size of the z axis.