# How to change the position and size of the labels of the ticks of the vertical colorbar of a seaborn's heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, heatmap

How to change the position and size of the labels of the ticks of the vertical color bar of a seaborn's heatmap?

I tried with the following code

```
ax.figure.axes[-1].yaxis.label.set_size(36)
ax.figure.axes[-1].yaxis.label.set_position((4, 1.0))
```

However, this does not work, i.e. the font size **of the labels of the ticks of the colorbar** remain in the same position with the same font size. I am also doing

```
colorbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
colorbar.set_ticks([-0.667, 0, 0.667])


# I want these labels to be bigger and more to the right!!
colorbar.set_ticklabels(['-1', '0', '1'])
```

With `colorbar.set_ticks([-0.667, 0, 0.667])`, I can change the vertical position of the ticks, but I also want the associated labels to be farther away from the tick themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The ticks of a colorbar are a bit confusing, as the positions need to be set via `colorbar.set_ticks()`, but when you want to change other parameters, you have to go back to the underlying axes. For vertical colorbars the y-axis is used.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195758/set-matplotlib-colorbar-size-to-match-graph/18195921#18195921) shows a way to always have the colorbar the same height as the main plot. The colorbar needs to be created outside `sns.heatmap`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

ax = sns.heatmap(np.random.uniform(-.6, .6, (6, 12)), cmap='inferno', vmin=-0.667, vmax=0.667, square=True, cbar=False)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax) 
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.1) 
cbar = plt.colorbar(ax.collections[0], cax=cax)
cbar.set_ticks([-0.667, 0, 0.667])
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['-1', '0', '1'], size=20)
cbar.ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', length=0, pad=15)
cbar.outline.set_edgecolor('black')
cbar.outline.set_linewidth(2)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: For some reason, now I only see the 1 and 0 labels on the right of the colorbar, i.e. the command `cbar.set_ticks([-0.667, 0, 0.667])` is not working as expected, but before it was working. Do you know why something would cause this?

Comment: If the lowest value in the heatmap is larger than `-0.667`, that value will not be present in the colorbar.  You can force the colormapping to be exactly between `-0.667` and `0.667` via the `vmin` and `vmax` parameters: `sns.heatmap(... vmin=-0.667, vmax=0.667)`.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem: I hadn't noticed I was setting `vmin` and `vmax`. Sorry if I annoy you, but have you ever experienced that the colorbar becomes taller/bigger than the heatmap if you set `square=True` (i.e. you force the heatmap to be squared)? Is there a way to ensure that the colorbar is always of the same height of the heatmap?

Comment: Thanks! That solved the other issue too! If I could, I would upvote this answer 3-4 times :D