# Adjust size of ConfusionMatrixDisplay (ScikitLearn)

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, data-science, confusion-matrix

How to set the size of the figure ploted by ScikitLearn's Confusion Matrix?

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay, confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(np.arange(25), np.arange(25))
cmp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(cm, display_labels=np.arange(25))
cmp.plot()
```

The code above shows this figure, which is too tight:

[image]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can send a [`matplotlib.axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html) object to the [`.plot`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.plot) method of [`sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html). Set the size of the figure in [`matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) first.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay, confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cm = confusion_matrix(np.arange(25), np.arange(25))
cmp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(cm, display_labels=np.arange(25))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
cmp.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: But now the legend overflows the matrix. Can we fix it?

Answer (score 9):

I was looking for how to adjust the colorbar as someone  pointed out in the commentaries in the answer offered by @Raphael and now want to add how to made this.

I used the properties of `ConfusionMatrixDisplay` and guided by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56900830/15879103) modified the code to:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay, confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cm = confusion_matrix(np.arange(25), np.arange(25))
cmp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(cm, display_labels=np.arange(25))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))

# Deactivate default colorbar
cmp.plot(ax=ax, colorbar=False)

# Adding custom colorbar
cax = fig.add_axes([ax.get_position().x1+0.01,ax.get_position().y0,0.02,ax.get_position().height])
plt.colorbar(cmp.im_,  cax=cax)
```

[image]