# ConfusionMatrixDisplay (Scikit-Learn) plot labels out of range

Tags: python, plot, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

The following code plots a confusion matrix:

```
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay

confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
target_names = ["aaaaa", "bbbbbb", "ccccccc", "dddddddd", "eeeeeeeeee", "ffffffff", "ggggggggg"]
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=confusion_matrix, display_labels=target_names)
disp.plot(cmap=plt.cm.Blues, xticks_rotation=45)
plt.savefig("conf.png")
```

[image: Confusion Matrix]

There are two problems with this plot.

1. The y-axis label is cut off (True Label). The x label is cut off too.
2. The names are to long for the x-axis.

To solve the first problem I tried to use `poof(bbox_inches='tight')` which is unfortunately not available for sklearn.
In the second case I tried the following solution for [2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66483409/adjust-size-of-confusionmatrixdisplay-scikitlearn) which lead to a completely distorted plot.

All in all I'm struggeling with both problems.

Comment: try  rcParams like `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (15,10)`. so changing Width, height.

Comment: tried out, nothing changed

Comment: is the line `plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (15,10)` added  before `disp.plot` ? or I mean need to be before the plot.

Comment: This actually did the job done. Now there is a large blank area around the plot. Do I need to crop it manually?

Comment: you can adjust (15,10)  so that its best fit for the labels.

Comment: Thanks! If you form it to a real answer, I will like it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to switch into `tight_layout` and add `pad_inches=` something.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import default_rng

rand = default_rng()
y_true = rand.integers(low=0, high=7, size=500)
y_pred = rand.integers(low=0, high=7, size=500)


confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
target_names = ["aaaaa", "bbbbbb", "ccccccc", "dddddddd", "eeeeeeeeee", "ffffffff", "ggggggggg"]
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=confusion_matrix, display_labels=target_names)
disp.plot(cmap=plt.cm.Blues, xticks_rotation=45)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("conf.png", pad_inches=5)
```

Result:

[image: Confusion matrix where all text in the axes is visible.]