How to control the height of the colorbar when using `plt` instead of `ax`?
A simple example:
a = np.random.random((10, 20))
plt.imshow(a, cmap='gray')
 
# Calculate (height_of_image / width_of_image)
im_ratio = a.shape[0]/a.shape[1]
 
# Plot vertical colorbar
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()


How to control the height of the colorbar when using plt instead of ax?
All the examples use fig, ax = plt.subplots but I just want to make one plot, and I want to make minimum change to my original code.

This question is similar to: Matplotlib: width of colorbar below a column of matshow and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195758/set-matplotlib-colorbar-size-to-match-graph#26720422. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The plt interface is just a shortcut to the ax interface. Internally, these are exactly the same functions. You can use ax = plt.gca() to "get the current ax", and work with the ax (matplotlib creates this automatically when the first plot command is encountered and no ax would be created yet).

Try this:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.random((10, 20))
plt.imshow(a, cmap='gray')

im_ratio = a.shape[0] / a.shape[1]

# Use the parameter `shrink` to fit the colorbar to your figure.
plt.colorbar(shrink=im_ratio)
plt.show()

For more information about the shrink parameter have a look here.
Edit
To always fit the colorbar try this:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

a = np.random.random((10, 20))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = plt.imshow(a, cmap='gray')

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
plt.show()

More information here.

This isn't what I want, it seems too short, but if I change (10, 20) to (50,20) it will be too long.

@Firestar-Reimu See my edit.

Use colorbar with the fraction parameter to scale the size of the colorbar.
The fraction parameter changes the size of the colorbar relative to the image; the default value is 0.15. You may adjust this value to make the colorbar longer or shorter. Have a look here
