# colorbar in python generates large size in default

Tags: python, plot, colorbar

I had a large colorbar I'd like to shrink to match my plot size. So I followed these two threads, [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195758/set-matplotlib-colorbar-size-to-match-graph) and [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702479/matplotlib-colorbar-placement-and-size), tried the magic code

"`colorbar(im,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)`".

However, it does not seem to work. I am wondering where I did wrong? Following is my code. I am totally new to python. Thanks.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
from matplotlib.pyplot import colorbar
from matplotlib.pyplot import close
from numpy import zeros as zeros

close('all')
img = zeros((250, 800))
im = imshow(img, cmap='gray'); colorbar(im,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)
```

The colorbar still looks large:
[image]

**Importantly:**

I'd prefer only to shorten the colorbar without making it thinner. Also, when the figure size changes, the colarbar can be size-changing accordingly.....like the MATLAB did, something like this:
[image]

when figure size changes, the colorbar resizes accordingly:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the size of the colorbar with `shrink` within `colorbar` easily.

Have a look at this:

```
img = zeros((250, 800))
im = imshow(img, cmap='gray')
colorbar(im,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04,shrink=0.46)
```

Leads to:
[image]

See [colorbar documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html) for more information.

Comment: I was thinking of only shortening the colorbar without making it thinner. Also, when the figure size changes, the colarbar can be size-changing accordingly.....like the MATLAB did.

Comment: I mean your answer is great, but I guess there is gotta be a relatively easy way to do it. I apologize  that I should have emphasize in the original thread.